# How to create a product without a variation?

Tags: commerce

I'm migrating to drupal commerce (kickstart 2) from woocommerce and contao isotope.

My biggest problem was/is understanding the terminology behind it - product types, variations, etc.

In woocommerce and isotope the product categories would be for example:
- Books
- Computers
- T-Shirts.

Each category would then have individual products in it, and each product would have optional variation.

I'm having hard time understanding this in kickstart2. More than that, is it even possible to create a product without variations? How can I create a store of simple unique products that would belong to different categories (woocommerce terminology), without variables.

For example:

- Books: product1, product2, product 3, ... (no variables)
- PCs: -- || --
  ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is - as You said - difference of terminology.
The easiest way for You would be trying this: https://simplytest.me/
Here You can quickly test Drupal modules and whole distributions. Please try Commerce Kickstart with this tool and during install click to install demo content.

There You'll see that Variations are more like Categories in Your meaning:
Each product display must have one or more product variations, which is why each product display type has a matching product variation type.
Different product variation types have different fields, used for storing images, attributes such as color and size, as well as any other information.

And Categories are more like taxonomy - You can list colors, sizes etc there and reuse it in multiple products.

Hope i helped You a little :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. So basically, I can create let's say variation type: books.
And then, I could put in several products in this "category" with only one variation:
- product 1
- product 2, ...etc.

Comment: Let's use this books example. 
So You have 5 different books to sell. 

First you create the categories - for informations about the books like:
 - Soft Case/Hard Case
 - Book / eBook etc 

Then You can create variation type: Books -> where You group those fields. 

Then You create a product of type Books -> and You fill the fields.
If You want to offer two kinds of the same product - like eBook/Book, or hardcase/softcase -> then You can create another variations for each type - they can vary in price etc.

For another book - you just create another product.

Comment: A product variation is a combination of fields. (More or less like a content type vanilla Drupal.) For books these fields could be author, title, description, etc. You can use the books variation for every book in your site. However, if you also want to sell lunchboxes, these fields are irrelevant. More interesting would be the size and the color. These would be new fields and you would require a new product variation for all lunchboxes. Variations are bundles of fields that products have in common.